# NSButton actions not being called in accessory view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, inputaccessoryview

I've created an accessory view in my storyboard which I've successfully added to an NSOpenPanel. The view is an NSView with an identifier of Accessory View, and it is contained within a view controller supported by a class I created called AccessoryViewController (id'ed as Open Accessory View). The view contains a pair of NSButtons (traditional pushbuttons) and a pair of NSTextField labels.

The buttons and labels are displayed in the Open Panel, as expected, but I don't seem to be getting IBActions when clicking on either of the buttons within the view, so I'm guessing I have something hooked up incorrectly.

The header for the accessory view (AccessoryViewController.h) looks like so:

```
@interface AccessoryViewController : NSViewController <NSOpenSavePanelDelegate>
{

}

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSOpenPanel *openPanel;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *visitingTeamLabel;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *homeTeamLabel;


@end
```

And the corresponding AccessoryViewController.m code:

```
@interface AccessoryViewController ()

@end

@implementation AccessoryViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do view setup here.
}

- (IBAction)visitingTeamButton:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)homeTeamButton:(id)sender {
}
```

The functions are empty for now, but the breakpoints I've placed on the functions never get triggered. I've verified that the buttons in the storyboard are hooked up to the IBActions (I control dragged them over to AccessoryViewController.m from the storyboard).

The Open Panel is created by choosing Open from the File menu and runs from within AppDelegate.m :

```
- (IBAction)openDirectory:(id)sender {
    NSOpenPanel* panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    NSStoryboard *storyBoard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; // get a reference to the storyboard
    NSViewController *accessoryView = [storyBoard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"Open Accessory View"];
    [panel setAccessoryView:[accessoryView view]];
    [panel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
    [panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [panel setAccessoryViewDisclosed:YES];

    [panel setDelegate:self];

    [panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
        if (result == NSModalResponseOK) {
            ;
        }
    }];
}
```

I'm kind of in the dark here (and still learning objective-c after 30+ years of Mac programming in C) so I'm hoping something immediately stands out for someone.
Thanks!

Comment: `beginWithCompletionHandler` starts the open panel and returns. `accessoryView` goes out of scope and is released.

Comment: Thank you. I changed things to use runModal instead, and everything is functioning as expected.